# Can you programmatically invoke siri?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to create a subclass of UITextView with a custom button to invoke Siri on (for its speech-to-text text entry). Is this possible? I don't mind if the keyboard is shown, I just want to provide my own button to turn on Siri.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that unfortunately (as of iOS 6.0). The only way to use Siri is to use `UITextFields` and let the user enter text by dictating to Siri.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Without using private APIs? Good luck.

Comment: The OP never specified. But i'll see what I can do using the runtime & public APIs.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I advise you to use some sort of obfuscation, e. g. base85- or RSA-encode the private classes and selector names you use... Then you can hit objc_getClass() etc. (Btw seen my iPod import library?)

Comment: @H2CO3 first I'm gonna make it work simple. I already have access to the keyboard layout, it's just a matter of toying with the right subviews to make siri pop up. Then I'll work on obfuscation.

Comment: Just an update: I'm able to now get the dictation button on-screen, and trying to figure out how to fire it (as it isn't a UIButton).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII maybe send a `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to the main window at that point, it will pass it down the responder chain. (i. e. simulate a touch.)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII or just class-dump.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's quite possible, but the one thing I don't want is for this to be device-specific.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that's your response to the simulated touch or to class-dump?

Comment: @H2CO3 no, what I'm saying is that I am dumping the classes - I just can't quite find the selector to fire the button - yet.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Any progress to report?

Comment: @0x7fffffff unfortunately, no. It appears that the keyboard on ios is not based off of the traditional UIView hierarchy, and simulating a touch did not appear to affect the keyboard. While I was able to access a class which indicated it was the Siri button, it did not have any methods to invoke to activate Siri.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Damn, it's really a shame there isn't any API for this. Thanks for putting the effort into trying though!

Comment: @0x7fffffff, you can accomplish the task [by simulating a home button long press, as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18671422/119114).