# Can Siri be invoked programmatically within my app using private APIs?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, siri

Instead of having the user to hold the home button, I would like to programmatically launch Siri within my application. Since there are no public APIs available to accomplish this, I would like to know, if anybody has been able to programmatically launch Siri via private API and if so which private API did you use?

I am not interested in any return values from Siri. All I want to do is to launch it.

Comment: iOS 6 onwards, requires entitlements to launch app even via private api. Still you can launch app programatically if you have a jailbroken phone. Is jailbroken solution acceptable?

Comment: @Bugivore, Siri isn't actually an "App", *per se*.  So, it doesn't launch like you would with other apps.  But, if you see below, I think I have a solution that works (it works for me).

Comment: @Nate - Great suggestion. Agree that it only uses private API so shouldn't need jailbroken phone..

Comment: I am not intending to submit this app to the Apple AppStore but I would prefer not to jailbreak the iPhone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on whether this is for an app that just won't go to the App Store (enterprise app, or personal/hobby app), or whether it will actually be run on *jailbroken* phones.

If you can rely on a jailbroken phone, and jailbreak utilities like MobileSubstrate, then I believe you can implement a method to open Siri just like [Ryan Petrich's libActivator does](https://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator/blob/master/LASimpleListener.x), as I [show in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15915452/119114).

However, if you are building for normal, *jailed* phones, I still think you can "hack" it (with Private APIs), by simulating the way the user opens Siri.  First, press the Home button, hold it for a bit, then release it.

This code works for me (iOS 6.1):

```
#import "GSEvent.h"
```

and

```
- (void)launchSiri {
   [self simulateTouchEvent: kGSEventMenuButtonDown];

   double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
   dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
   dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      [self simulateTouchEvent: kGSEventMenuButtonUp];
   });
}

- (void)simulateTouchEvent: (GSEventType)type
{
   struct GSEventRecord record;
   memset(&record, 0, sizeof(record));
   record.type = type;
   record.timestamp = GSCurrentEventTimestamp();
   GSSendSystemEvent(&record);  
}
```

This relies on having the GSEvent.h header, which isn't part of the public set of headers.  I believe I got mine [here, as well as GSWindow.h that it pulls in](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/GraphicsServices/GSEvent.h).  Obviously, you'd then need to download these two headers and add them to your project.

This code is in the **GraphicsServices** private framework, so you'll also need to add that framework to your project.  Do so just like adding a normal framework, but you need to browse to somewhere like

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework
```

to find it (path adjusted for your Xcode installation directory, and SDK).

<sub>*Disclaimer: I did test this on a jailbroken phone, but it was definitely inside a normal app, installed in the `/var/mobile/Applications/` sandbox area, and I'm 99% sure I haven't done anything that depends on being jailbroken.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Nope. No access to Siri. I am pretty sure that if you do get access, somehow, Apple will reject your app. (but I can think of many more who will be appreciative)

There is this, though: http://ps3trophies.com/forums/apple/6458-siri-cracked-now-even-android-users-can-use-siri.html

See this answer as well:https://stackoverflow.com/a/12607905/2535467