# Send a command to Siri

Tags: ios, ios10, siri, sirikit

There are [several hundred commands](https://hey-siri.io/), over a thousand variations, that Siri will accept and act on.  For example, "Schedule a meeting with Sean tomorrow at 1 PM" will create an entry in your Calendar.

Is there any way for an application (non-jailbroken / appstore approved) to send Siri (or its subsystem) these commands? Not via voice - just my app sending Siri the text string it already understands and having it act on the command. I don't want to launch Siri, just have it process the command initiated by my app, instead of via voice.

I understand that the Sirikit is designed to have Siri send commands to apps, not the other way around, but I was hoping there was some way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Siri be invoked programmatically within my app using private APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649602/can-siri-be-invoked-programmatically-within-my-app-using-private-apis)

Comment: Maybe... it's a different question, but the answer may be the same.  I've never developed an iPhone app, but have an idea for one, but it would require Siri to accept several of her pre-programmed commands.  I would only build it if I could put it in the Apple App store.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with Siri.  But Apple provides the libraries for interacting with the underlying system components.  For example, check out [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit) for working with reminders or a user's calendar.

Comment: My hope was to get access to Disable Wifi, Disable Bluetooth, especially now that Apple has made it more difficult to actually turn it off.  I'd like to create a geofencing app.  I thought Siri might be a way around the restriction.