# Launch iOS dictation in multiple languages without the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, microphone, dictation

I'd like to create an app for iOS that can use the dictation function of the keyboard, without that the user click on the microphone icon of the keyboard (a button of the app would launch the listening of the dictated text). Is there any way of doing this? And should I use swift or objective C to do so?

Another thing I'd like to do is make this dictation works with different languages. Can I do that when the user did not select this language in his keyboard settlngs?

Thank you for your help and for your answers.

Comment: 1. In simple words, you can  not . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649602/can-siri-be-invoked-programmatically-within-my-app-using-private-apis

Comment: 2. You can use 3rd party API for voice recognition (not Siri), voice dictation (ask google) and remark: "Apple restricts its API to keep third-party keyboards from using iOS voice dictation." (http://www.cultofmac.com/303653/apple-limits-dictation-keyboard/)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But are there any third party API with similar kind of quality of speech recognition? I mean that this Apple technology is pretty reliable, and I'm not sure all of them are the same